# Android Permission Denied when reading photo

Tags: android, gallery, photos, permission-denied

I'm trying to read a photo off the Android device gallery to display in my app.

My app allows a user to select an image from the gallery and this code within an onActivityResult() method saves the filename for later use:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

      Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), filePathColumn, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();

      int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
      String filename = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
      cursor.close();
}
```

I then later try to display the photo in another activity like so:

```
  ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(photoFilename));
  Log.i("AddInformationDialog", "URI found: " + uri);
  photoImageView.setImageURI(uri)
```

But I'm getting this Permission Denied error:

```
WARN/ImageView(14618): Unable to open content: file:///mnt/sdcard/dcim/Camera/2012-05-31_09-37-03_660.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/dcim/Camera/2012-05-31_09-37-03_660.jpg (Permission denied)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
```

I looked at the Manifest permissions and didn't see one that explicitly allowed an app to read from the filesystem.  What am I missing?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite**

I couldn't re-create your error, perhaps it is a Droid Bionic specific issue. The only things I can think of are that: the file doesn't allow read access or it has a lock on it preventing the read. Here's a shot in the dark:

```
  ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
  File file = new File(photoFilename);
  file.setReadable(true);
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  Log.i("AddInformationDialog", "URI found: " + uri);
  photoImageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: Do I need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when I'm just reading from it?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, I read your question too fast. I cannot re-create your Permission Denied error and the Apache source code doesn't point anything obvious. Could you provide some more detail? Does this happen with every file or just this one?

Comment: It happens with every file.  I loaded it on a different phone and am now getting a memory error, so it looks like it could be specific to the Droid Bionic I was running on.  It at least tried to load the image on a Samsung Captivate.  The problem is, my customer needs it to run on the Bionic.

Comment: I don't have access to a Bionic myself, but I updated my answer.

Comment: My SonyEriccson does wierd things if it's plugged in. I have to "disconnect" the phone memory card!